# Is Vietnam an autocracy or a republic?

Tags: republic, vietnam, autocracy

I am not really sure about the difference in meaning of "autocratic" and "republican". The only thing in my mind is that autocratic is a country where power is centered around one person, and a republic is a country where power is divided among a group of people.

In Vietnam, I saw that they have a Congress, and a decision is made by the approval of those in the Congress. But in many statements, I saw people state that Vietnam, along with China and Russia are three autocratic countries.

Comment: The three countries share the similarity in all social-economic matters are dominated by a single party with absolute powers, opposite voices are suppressed at any cost

Comment: These aren't the only two choices.

Comment: Words can have their meanings redefined, especially political terms. If country A is friends with superpower B, then B would call A a country ruled by "the choice of people/democracy" regardless of whether or not that is really the case.

Comment: [The government of the French _Republic_ is entrusted to an _emperor_...](https://www.napoleon-series.org/research/government/legislation/c_constitution12.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any such terms, the quest for academic definitions is overshadowed by common use. Almost everybody understands that a "Democratic People's Republic" is usually none of these things.

- A republic is often defined as a government by the [elected representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representative_democracy) of the people, with strong overtones of the [rule of law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law).
- Autocracy is often defined as a government by a [single person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocracy), who does not derive legitimacy from the consent of the people.
- A [people's republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_republic) in the socialist/communist pattern claims to derive their authority from the consent of the working classes, often with a [cadre party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_party) which claims to understand the needs and wishes of the people better than those people could articulate at the ballot box.

Vietnam formally has the trappings of a socialist/communist republic, with elements of collective rule by the party leadership. It has been described as [authoritarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) moving towards [autocratic](https://www.dw.com/en/is-vietnam-sliding-deeper-into-authoritarianism/a-45769864), but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 6):

The terms *republic* and *autocracy* are not mutually exclusive.

A republic is best understood in contrast to a monarchy. Most European states (and likely a majority around the world) were headed by a single person as the supreme head of government in some form before the First World War. The important part, however, is that this ruler's powers would (in almost all cases) automatically pass on to their heir upon the ruler's passing. Often, these rulers would be styled as King, sometimes Emperor, but all levels of aristocracy could head a territory in such a way and especially Germany is well known for having had monarchies whose head merely held the title of Count.

Most European monarchies fell in the aftermath of the First World War but some – notably the United Kingdom but also the Netherlands, Sweden or Denmark – survived and these countries remain monarchies to this day. However, most *political* power has been removed from the hands of these monarchs over time and while they still hold the highest ceremonial post in their respective nations they have very little input on actual policies.

In contrast to this, a republic is a state where the person at the top does not automatically pass on their powers to their heir in the same way. One of the earliest modern cases was the United States which chose to *elect* a President to hold the highest ceremonial role. However, the election part is not necessary (or indeed even sufficient, as electoral monarchies existed): for example, the USSR was definitely a Republic but there were no elections (especially not by the general public) to determine who would lead the state.

The USSR is also a good example because the highest political power was wielded by a number of people who were not related to each other and thus it cannot be said that any of these directly inherited the power of their predecessor as the heir of a monarch would.

Whether or not a country is commonly seen as a republic or monarchy often depends on relatively minor details. If the head of state styles themselves as President, Generalissimo or another title that is generally not hereditary, general opinion will generally lean towards calling the state a republic. On the other hand, the head of state calling themself Queen or Empress and the consitution (if extant) stating that power will pass on to the oldest offspring, a country will generally be called a monarchy.

Of course, there are edge cases, the most obvious being North Korea where a single family has held power for 70 years and passed it on from father to son while still calling itself a republic and not using royal titles for the leader. Indeed, I have seen some commentators call it a monarchy already.

---

An *autocracy* describes a form of government which wields significant control over its people and does not allow them to fully decide their fate. The term is most often contrast with *democracy* and, to a lesser extent, *totalitarian system*.

In a democracy, most obviously, central political decisions are referred to the populace. In most modern democracies this means that the general population gets to elect a government of some form (but not necessarily the head of state; monarchies can be democracies, too). However, the Swiss model where the population routinely votes on legislation at the national, regional and communal level is equally possible.

An autocracy will not grant its population that freedom, instead ensuring that the ruling clique will remain in power. However, autocracies generally allow freedom in sectors where the power of the government is not in danger. In contrast to this, a totalitarian system will often attempt to influence the minds and choices of its people so that they necessarily embrace the state ideology. A historic example of this would again be the Soviet Union where the population was not only expected to accept the rule of the Communist Party but also support its socialist ideas and speaking out against anything that was official ideology was dangerous for the individual (even if the speech did not endanger the power of the ruling clique in any way).

The terms *totalitarian system* and *autocracy* tend to get messy and they are not always easily distinguished, so they are often lumped into the more general *dictatorship*. But even then, the boundary between dictatorships and democracies can get equally muddy, especially when the ruling clique has widespread popular support and easily wins elections without resorting to manipulation.

---

I cannot provide a fully accurate classification of what Vietnam is, as I have not studied their system sufficiently. However, it can be said that it is best classified as a Republic, as the holder and wielder of political power as well as the head of state are not hereditary positions and they do not claim any title typically associated with a monarchy (instead they have the title of President, which generally points to a republic).

Comment: Just curious, how do you classify China - a republic, democracy, or autocrat? The social-political system of Vietnam is quite similar to China.

Comment: @r13 you can classify based on a widely-cited in peer-reviewed academic papers  the **Economist Intelligent Unit Democratic index** (newly updated 2020), see here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index)

Comment: China is a fully authoritarian country based on this index